# Typo3 V9 redirect strips virtual subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, http-redirect, typo3-9.x

I have a Typo3 V 9.5.30 installation. In this system runs 2 sites with different domains. Both are configured as //domain.tld.
When i call it with www. it redirects to non-www that works. When i call it like [www.domain.tld/subfolder](http://www.domain.tld/subfolder) (not an existing folder, but an configured static route to an subpage in the system) it will be redirect to domain.tld/index.php. Why this happens? In the htaccess i add the folowing rules:

```
# ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

following redirect i want:

```
http://www.domain.tld/subfolder -> https://domain.tld/subfolder
```

Im out of any idea, anyone can help?

my .htaccess looks like:

```
#####
#
# Example .htaccess file for TYPO3 CMS - for use with Apache Webserver
#
# This file includes settings for the following configuration options:
#
# - Compression
# - Caching
# - MIME types
# - Cross Origin requests
# - Rewriting and Access
# - Miscellaneous
# - PHP optimisation
#
# If you want to use it, you have to copy it to the root folder of your TYPO3 installation (if its
# not there already) and rename it to '.htaccess'. To make .htaccess files work, you might need to
# adjust the 'AllowOverride' directive in your Apache configuration file.
#
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3 installation!
#            Consider adding this file's content to your webserver's configuration directly for speed improvement
#
# Lots of the options are taken from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess
#
####


### Begin: Compression ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# *) Uncomment the following lines and
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 for the Backend
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 together with the TypoScript properties
#    config.compressJs and config.compressCss for GZIP compression of Frontend JS and CSS files.

#<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/css" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
    # enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
    # and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
    # the core directives.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
            application/javascript \
            application/json \
            application/ld+json \
            application/manifest+json \
            application/rdf+xml \
            application/rss+xml \
            application/schema+json \
            application/vnd.geo+json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
            application/x-font-ttf \
            application/x-javascript \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
            application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml \
            font/eot \
            font/opentype \
            image/bmp \
            image/svg+xml \
            image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
            image/x-icon \
            text/cache-manifest \
            text/css \
            text/html \
            text/javascript \
            text/plain \
            text/vcard \
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
            text/vtt \
            text/x-component \
            text/x-cross-domain-policy \
            text/xml
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip svgz
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

### End: Compression ###



### Begin: Browser caching of resource files ###

# This affects Frontend and Backend and increases performance.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>

### End: Browser caching of resource files ###


### Begin: MIME types ###

# Proper MIME types for all files
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # Data interchange
    AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
    AddType application/json                            json map topojson
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
    AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
    AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
    AddType application/xml                             rdf xml

    # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js

    # Manifest files
    AddType application/manifest+json                   webmanifest
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache

    # Media files

    AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
    AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
    AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

    # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
    AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>

# UTF-8 encoding
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .manifest .rdf .rss .vtt .webapp .webmanifest .xml
</IfModule>

### End: MIME types ###



### Begin: Cross Origin ###

# Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Allow cross-origin access to web fonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

### End: Cross Origin ###



### Begin: Rewriting and Access ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
    # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
    RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

    # Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]

    # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

    # Access block for folders
    RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) - [F]
    RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

    # Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
    # the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

    # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
    # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
    RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

    # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
    # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# Access block for files
# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    <FilesMatch "(?i:^\.|^#.*#|^(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|^composer\.(?:json|lock)|^ext_conf_template\.txt|^ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|^ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*|rc)|.*~)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# Apache ≥ 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(?i:/\.|/\x23.*\x23|/(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|/composer\.(?:json|lock)|/ext_conf_template\.txt|/ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|/ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*|rc)|.*~)$#">
        Require all denied
    </If>
</IfModule>

# Block access to vcs directories
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.(?:git|svn|hg)/
</IfModule>

### End: Rewriting and Access ###



### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# 404 error prevention for non-existing redirected folders
Options -MultiViews

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled.
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Force IE to render pages in the highest available mode
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff2?|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

    # Reducing MIME type security risks
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ETag removal
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None

### End: Miscellaneous ###


# Add your own rules here.


# ssl
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "Both are configured as //domain.tld." - What does that mean? Please include your complete `.htaccess` file. It sounds like you have a conflict. (The directives you've posted won't cause this redirect by themselves.)

Comment: That meaned the configuration inside the typo3. I shortened to domain.tld but typo3 set the // in front of them. i add my current htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the directives in the wrong place. These redirects need to go at the top of the file, not at the end.

By placing these directives at the end, after the front-controller, the request is internally rewritten to `/index.php` before the redirect occurs so ends up redirecting to `/index.php`, not the URL being requested.

You can literally just move these two rules to the very top of the `.htaccess` file. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Comment: that to the trick! many thanks! :)